# BottomAppBar covers Hamburger Menu bottom part

Tags: winrt-xaml, template10

When implementing  and the Hamburger Menu pane opens, the bottom part (Setting) is covered/hidden by the BottomAppBar.

Comment: You should mark an answer so this question looks closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pleased to tell you that a Template 10 sample project demonstrating how to implement Bottom App Bar already exists and you can review it on GitHub.

> https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples/BottomAppBar

Answer (score 1):

Solution:
Simply add another grid row to your page and implement a CommandBar there:

```html
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <... Grid.Row="0"/>
        <... Grid.Row="1"/>
        <CommandBar Grid.Row="2"/>
</Grid>
```